# aircrack no such device

Tags: aircrack-ng, macbook-air

I have a MacBook Air 2011 with Xubuntu installed. Previously on Xubuntu 14.04, I updated to 16.04. Before the update, aircrack was working fine with my wireless card, but now it's giving me this output.

I tried killing all the processes without it changing anything.
What can I do? Since the only internet connection I have now is on my phone.

```
iwconfig
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.


sudo airmon-ng start wlp2s0

Found 2 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
1774    avahi-daemon
1780    avahi-daemon


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlp2s0      Broadcom    wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)


sudo airodump-ng mon0
Interface mon0: 
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
```

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00e9]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I think `wl` is a wrong driver. Anyway it doesn't support monitor mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed a wrong driver for this adapter that doesn't support monitor mode.

Remove it by

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This device will be handled by `brcmsmac` module that does support monitor.

Comment: It's unable to locate the packages bcmwl-kernel and source

Comment: I fixed a typo. Run again. it is one package.